# Java How to count how many elements in an array have a range?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to import data from a text file. This is the content of the file:

15
49 50 51 59 0 5 9 10 15 19 50 55 89 99 100

The first number is supposed to stand for the number of test scores. The second row of numbers contains the individual test score.

I am using `BufferedReader`, and `StringTokenizer` to read the data and put it into `int[] anArray;`. The variable `int number1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);` is supposed to save the first line of text(the total amount of all test scores). Then I initialize `anArray = new int[number1];` to store all the test scores in it. I succeeded in doing this task. And because all arrays start at `[0]`, I initialize variable int `readnumber = number1 -1;`
This is the chunk of code that initializes `int[] anArray;`:

```
int x = readnumber;
    for (x = readnumber; x >= 0; x--)
    {
      s2 = st.nextToken();
      anArray[x] = Integer.parseInt(s2);
      countarray[x] = Integer.parseInt(s2);


      //System.out.println ("    Token is: " + s2);
      //System.out.println (anArray[x]);
    }
```

I am supposed to create an array that would go through `int[] anArray;` and count the test scores. I am supposed to save these test scores in a range. 0 -9, 10 - 29, 30 - 39, 40 - 49, 50 - 59, 60 - 69, 70- 79, 80 - 89, 90 - 100.

This is a kind of statistic. I am supposed to separate the individual values of `int[] anArray;` and put them into the above ranges in a new array. So I created the array `countarray[x] = Integer.parseInt(s2);`. I made a code that finds the minimum and maximum range values based on the input. Every time the loop goes through `int[] anArray;` and finds that the `[x]` value of the array fits in between the minimum and maximum of the range, it is supposed to add `1` to the array `int[] countarray;` and move to the next one. That is how it would find how many `int[] anArray;` values fit into a specific range parameters. The other code around that loop just determines the range parameters from the input, so that they are flexible, and not "hard-wired" into the code.

I can't make this program work. I think it's just an error in the syntax of the `int[] countarray;`. Can you guys look into it? All the other loops and calculations must stay.

```
Here is my main code:
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GradesHistogram
{
  public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException
  {

    String s1;
    String s2;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("grades.in.txt"));
    s1 = br.readLine();
    System.out.print(s1);
    System.out.println("\n");
    int number1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    //System.out.println("Number1 is " +number1);
    int[] anArray;           
    anArray = new int[number1];   
    anArray[0] = 1; 
    int[] countarray;
    countarray = new int[number1];   
    countarray[0] = 1; 

    System.out.println(s1);
    s2 = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(s2);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (s2);

    int readnumber = number1 -1;
    int x = readnumber;
    for (x = readnumber; x >= 0; x--)
    {
      s2 = st.nextToken();
      anArray[x] = Integer.parseInt(s2);
      countarray[x] = Integer.parseInt(s2);


      //System.out.println ("    Token is: " + s2);
      //System.out.println (anArray[x]);
    }
    int histogrammin = 0;
    int histogrammax = 0;
    x = readnumber;
    for (int histogramrows = 0; histogramrows < 10; histogramrows++)
    {

      histogrammin = histogramrows * 10;

      if (histogrammin == 90)
      {
      histogrammax = histogrammin + 10;


      }
      else 
      {
        histogrammax = histogrammin + 9;
        for (x = 0; x < 14; x++)
        {
          if (histogrammin <= anArray[x] && anArray[x] <= histogrammax)
          {
            countarray[x]++;
            System.out.println("countarray = "+countarray[x]);
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you turn this into a minimal example that produces that error?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit on "I can't make this program work."  What's not working?  Does it crash?  Are the calculations wrong?  You need to provide some more detail on the problem you're actually having.

Comment: The calculations are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly read in the data into `anArray`, the error is with the final `for` loop. Instead of iterating over grade ranges, why not iterate over the grades themselves, and classify them into an interval?

Since it's homework, you need to try to rewrite that loop, we're not going to do it for you. Continue using `System.out.println` to help you debug your program, and take it one step at a time.